# How to resolve this bash python interaction?

Tags: python, bash

I have 3 files, let's see one by one.

`params.conf`

```
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
[e]
```

`parsing.py`

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('params.conf')

lst=parser.sections()
print lst
```

`demo.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash
value=$(python parsing.py)
echo "$value"
```

After running `demo.sh`, i should get the output `['a','b','c','d','e']` and I am getting that.

But, there are several problem when I am going to the next level.

- I want to use the list elements, so at this moment I need to use `sed` to parse it within bash file which I don't want, rather i love to access the `list` as an array in bash so that i can use it later.
- Currently I am printing a `list`, but I can't always do that. Because I could have multiple `list` in my python file, and I just can't afford to print each of them and retrieve it from bash. So, can I return a variable from python to bash somehow, I am searching some hack like `source` a `bash` file from another `bash` file.
- Eventually I want to have multiple functions in my `python` file and will try to access a particular functions return value from bash. Can i achieve that? Like rather calling a whole `python` file, can I call a specific `function` from a `python` file?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use sed to parse the output of the python script.

In python script before printing the output, convert the list into space separated string (hope you do not have any item in list with space in it)

```
print " ".join(lst)
```

This output can be easily looped through in shell.
For me the following code gives the below output.

```
#! /bin/bash
lst=$(python parsing.py)
for i in $lst
do
    echo $i
done
```

params.conf is same as yours...

**output**

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Hope this helps in solving some of your problem..

Also calling a specific function in python from shell script can be achieved like below...

python file with multiple function

```
import sys

def foo():
    print 'i am foo'

def func():
    print 'i am func'

def bye():
    print 'i am bye'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)==2:
        x = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], sys.argv[1])
        x()
```

and shell script (i am using command line args to name what is the python function)

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $(python params.py $1)
```

output...

```
# ./demo.sh foo
i am foo
# ./demo.sh func
i am func
# ./demo.sh bye
i am bye
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really a great help, +1.